# Maven versioning for multiprofile project

Tags: java, maven, versioning

I need to support two builds with some set of differences in libraries versions, so I made two build profiles and this works fine, but now I have a versioning problem while preparing a release.

I use the `major.minor.revision-qualifier` versioning schema, where:

- `major` - a breaking change
- `minor`  - a backward-compatible changes (new features)
- `revision` - a bug fix
- `qualifier` - the only qualifier I use now is `SNAPSHOT` to mark unreleased versions.

But since now I have two builds, I need to add some qualifiers to release versions e.g. `1.8.0-v1` and `1.8.0-v2`, but then I won't be able to have two `SNAPSHOT` versions. Or I need to break the "rules" about `major\minor` version usage and make two "branches" e.g. release `1.8.0` and `1.9.0` and then increase only last number no matter when fixing a bug or adding a new features.

I have a feeling like I am doing something antipattern, could anyone please give me some advice?

***P.S.*** I already have heavily reworked `2.x` version, so I can't have separate "branches" as `2.x` and `1.x` versions, unless i change this new version to `3.0`

***upd***

I guess i can't make this story short, so here we go.

In my project i use to have `ojdbc6` and `aqapi` jars(oracle libraries), my app was working on `java 7` and `Apache ServiceMix 5` with `oracle 11` database. But then some clients updated to oracle 12 and i need new libraries for that, but they only work on `java 8`, but ActiveMQ i am using as part of `ServiceMix 5` doesn't work on `java 8`. So i updated to `servicemix 7` and and after some chances it works fine. So rest of the difference in build profiles are versions of servicemix provided libraries (a complete list is redundant here i guess).

In the end despite the fact that new jdbc driver is fully compatible with old database(not completely sure about aqapi and client side of ActiveMQ, but they should be also compatible), i can't force every client to update and reinstall java\servicemix at the same time, but i still wanna be able to fix\add stuff for all of them.

So i need to support two builds for different versions of servicemix, at least for now(its a temporary solution, but as proverb says: there is nothing more permanent than temporary, so i want to make it in the most right way possible)

***P.S.***
I decided to make profiles instead of separate brunch in VCS, because it looks like much easier solution, but it doesn't metter in terms of the versioning problem.

Comment: I guess that build profiles are not the best approach for this. What is the difference between the two versions of the project and why do they exist?

Comment: Profiles are simply the wrong approach as you already realised you will get issues for a release. The question is: Why do you need different libraries/versions? If so make separate modules which have different deps/versions and release in one go ....and keep semantic versioning...

Comment: I'm guessing that you're writing this question because the second you added the -v1 and -v2 you realised that you were doing something wrong. Respond to the question in@JFMeier's comment and you will probably see the answer as you do so.

Answer (score 0):

So as @Software Engineer said, after thinking about reasons and writing a post update i realised its not multiprofile problem, it's purely versioning problem, it would be the absolutely the same if i make brunch in VCS.

So in the end i decided to make `1.x.x` and `2.x.x` versions despite the fact that changes are not that "breaking", but they are not fully backward-compatible(even tho new version can work with old database it still needs new servicemix).

This multiprofile workaround doesn't looks pretty, but i left it there, it allows me to build both versions in one go(i use `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion` command after the first build) and i don't need to support two brunches this way, so it saves some time.